# How would one update Button Image I.e. `Image(SystemName)` when pressed swiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

So I'm new to Swift and this is probably a fairly silly question. But, I'm looking for a way to update a buttons `Image(systemName)` when pressed by the user. I've found a few examples online, but I'm struggling to grasp the concept of `UIButton` and `Button`.

**My Current Button**

```
// lock State (Set in struct ContentView: View)
@State var isViewLocked:Bool = false

// View Lock Button
Button(action: {
    isViewLocked.toggle()
}, label: {
    Image(systemName: "lock")
        .font(.system(size: 25,
            weight: .regular,
            design: .default))
        .foregroundColor(selectedIndex == number ? Color(.systemBlue) : Color(UIColor.lightGray))
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out.

```
// lock State (Set in struct ContentView: View)
@State var isViewLocked:Bool = false

// View Lock Button
Button(action: {
    self.isViewLocked.toggle()
}, label: {
    Image(systemName: self.isViewLocked ? "lock.slash" : "lock")
        .font(.system(size: 25,
            weight: .regular,
            design: .default))
        .foregroundColor(selectedIndex == number ? Color(.systemBlue) : Color(UIColor.lightGray))
})
```

Comment: no need ```self.isViewLocked == true ``` simply use ```self.isViewLocked ? "lock.slash" : "lock"```

Comment: Right you are, I've updated my answer. +1